# Submit spark job to AWS EMR with java code and wait for the execution and get final status

Tags: java, apache-spark, amazon-emr

I am trying to submit a spark job to AWS EMR via the AWS EMR SDK APIs.
I want the process to submit the job and then wait for the job to complete/fail and get the respective status.

Code:

```
    AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
AmazonElasticMapReduce emr =
        AmazonElasticMapReduceClientBuilder
                .standard()
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))
                .build();

HadoopJarStepConfig sparkStepConf =
        new HadoopJarStepConfig()
                .withJar("command-runner.jar")
                .withArgs("spark-submit")
                .withArgs("--master", "yarn")
                .withArgs(sparkJarPath)
                .withArgs(args);

StepConfig sparkStep =
        new StepConfig().withName("Spark Step").withActionOnFailure(ActionOnFailure.CONTINUE).withHadoopJarStep(
                sparkStepConf);

AddJobFlowStepsRequest req =
        new AddJobFlowStepsRequest().withJobFlowId(clusterId).withSteps(Collections.singletonList(sparkStep));
emr.addJobFlowSteps(req);
```

Couldn't find something to fetch the status of submitted jobs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a example (please check for emptiness in certain areas of code):

```
ListStepsResult stepsResult = emr.listSteps(new ListStepsRequest().withClusterId(clusterId).withStepIds(req.getStepIds()));
List<StepSummary> stepsList = stepsResult.getSteps();
StepSummary stepSummary = stepsList.get(0);
StepStatus stepSummaryStatus = stepSummary.getStatus();
String stepStatus = stepSummaryStatus.getState();
StepExecutionState stepState = StepExecutionState.valueOf(stepStatus);
```

stepState will have what you want.